# compile apache httpd server with apache2.conf as main configuration file

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, httpd.conf

My English is poor, thank you for your patience!

I compiled apache httpd server and installed normally. It can work correctly. The configuration file is /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf. But we known that install apache on ubuntu use: apt-get install apache2, will have the main configuration file in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and other separate configuration files.

My question is how to compile apache httpd server from source code and generate the configuration files structure same with apache2.conf not the httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mimic Debian/Ubuntu layout you have to follow these simple steps.

HTTPD configure comes with an option called , and I'm citing the docs here:

> --enable-layout=LAYOUT

Where **LAYOUT** is the name of a layout defined in the file **config.layout**  you obtain when you download the source code to compile.

Since "Debian" is already defined there in that file, you just invoke it:

> --enable-layout=Debian

This along with this other option to change the binary name and config file as you requested:

> --with-program-name apache2

should do the trik.

So briefly:

```
./configure --enable-layout=Debian --with-program-name=apache2
```

...and any other options for configure you deem necessary.